# MySQLi find and delete all data for a user ID which no longer exists

Tags: php, mysqli, cron, jobs

My database set up may become cluttered with data from old users due to there being so many different tables which contain user information.

I am looking to run a cron job which will search `ap_users` (the main user table) for `user_id` and then use that information to check all other tables for any `user_id` which does not exist in the `ap_users` table and delete/remove those records.

I am wondering what would be the quickest and most efficient way of doing this? As I am unsure on how to check for a `user_id` which doesn't exist?

I have attempted something like this which doesn't seem to work, once I can get this working, I can progress it to the rest of the database:

```
$mysqli_find = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ap_user_points WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM ap_users group by user_id)");
while ($found_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli_find)){
$user_id = $found_rows['user_id'];
echo $user_id;
}
```

Comment: You can use mySql `NOT IN` inside your query.

Comment: This is a bit broad, what code have you considered?  Once you do figure this out, this is a good reason to use foreign keys with on delete cascade.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I noticed, I have added what I have already attempted above.

Comment: replace `*` with `user_id` in the outer Query..

Comment: and remove the `Group by user_id` from the Sub Query